# How to make an if statement using only a part of the date?

Tags: ios, if-statement, nsdate

I get a transaction date stamp from an API. The format is MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a (02/01/2014 11:41 23s AM) .

So what i want to do is color the text of the transaction label in which the  object falls in according to the variance from a certain date.

In my case, that certain date is the current time.

So you can see below, that I have an if statement for this. However I don't want them to be how it currently is, because it limits the flexibility of the statement.

My question is for two scenarios:
1) How do I make the condition statement so  if the transactionDate is 1 hour away from the current date, datelabel.textcolor is red, else green.

2) If the transactionDate is not the same day ?

I am having trouble determining how to implement these conditions. Please let me know how it's done in case 1 and case 2.

You can see problem I have, the statement is so rigid, I can only make statements but they too accurate, and I want a wider/specific margin.

Right now it is so specific, that if my goal is to make transactionDatetime one hour away, color textcolor green, I cannot because either datestring equals exact time like 2/01/2014 10:00 43s AM, or anything else is inequal.

I want to make anything more than 1 hour inequal (colors anything beside green) and anything under 1 hour equal (textcolor green).

I can take care of everything, just need help loosening this time frame.

```
        NSNumber *timestamp = [payment objectForKey:@"transactionDatetime"];
        NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];


        NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
        // format it
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
        // convert it to a string
        NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
        // free up memory
        [dateFormat release];
        //Try it
        NSLog(@"Todays date is = %@",dateString);



        if ([dateLabel.text isEqual:dateString]) {
            dateLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:50/255.0f green:197/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        }
        else {
            dateLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:68/255.0f green:140/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        }
        dateLabel.text = [df stringFromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:([timestamp floatValue]/1000)]];
        [df release];
```

Comment: Side note - why do you create two date formatters with the same format? Just create and use one of them.

Comment: i have tried that to no avail. will try again .

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to use is NSDateComponents.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html

So if you wanted weekday you would do something like :

```
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents =
[gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
int weekday = [weekdayComponents weekday];
```

so for your case just grab time!

Comment: actually i just realized what I am doing is fine, but the only problem is i haven't set the slack time. So since I said if at maximum, transactionDatetime should be green if transactiontime stamp is at most 1 hour older than current time -- i'd have to modify my condition.  Any clue  on modifying ([dateLabel.text isEqual:dateString])  so anything in between (dateString - 1 hour) is accepted ?

Comment: Are you trying to subtract 1 from a string?

Comment: in theory at least yes. I just want the condition modified so anything that falls between datestring and (datestring - one hour) allows me to form a condition.

Comment: You would have to work with NSDate or write some type of string parsing algorithm if you are set on doing it that specific way.